# How to change the color of a textfield dynamically in sencha?

Tags: css, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

How to change the color of a textfield dynamically in sencha? I have tried these below mentioned methods:

```
Ext.getCmp('fieldId').setStyle('color:red;');

Ext.getCmp('fieldId')setFieldStyle('color:red');

Ext.getCmp('fieldId').setCls('updateColor');

Ext.getCmp('fieldId').addCls('updateColor');

Ext.getCmp('fieldId').btnInnerEl.setStyle({color:"red"});
```

css file:

```
.updateColor{
color: red;
    }
```

None of the above works. How can we change the textfield color dynamically?

Comment: Are you looking to change the text color or the background color?

Comment: How about something like this? var el = Ext.get('myElementId');
el.addClass('myClass');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try making the css definition as

```
.updateColor .x-form-label,.updateColor .x-form-field{
    color: red;
}
```

and then use the line

```
Ext.getCmp('fieldId').setCls('updateColor');
```